# What is the Oracle equivalent to MS SQL Server Management Studio FREE EDITION?

Tags: database, oracle

What is the Oracle equivalent to MS SQL Server Management Studio FREE EDITION?

Please note there are other similar questions on SO, but they do not provide answers for a FREE VERSION.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Oracle Sql Developer

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) is more information.

Comment: For some reason it returns an error when trying to download in the US. This is free, correct?